# How to select rows of structured numpy array with certain sequence

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

I have a structured numpy array `all_people`. I want to find certain people by `id`, with a given sequence. And update their ages.

```
import numpy as np

all_people = np.array([(1, 10), (2, 20), (3, 30), (4, 40), (5, 50)],
                      dtype=[('id', int), ('age', float)])

chosen_id = [4, 5, 1]

# So I want to choose 3 persons with id equals to 4, 5, and 1,
# and also with the same sequence.
# Then add 1 age to people with id 4, add 2 age to people with id 5, 
#  and add 3 age to people with id 1.

# I have tried the following code but it does not work
mask = np.isin(all_people['id'], chosen_id)
all_people['age'][mask] += [1, 2, 3]

# The resulting all_people['age'] is 
#    array([11., 20., 30., 42., 53.])
```

The reason that the above code does not work is that `mask` and `np.isin` does not use the sequence defined by `chosen_id`.

Could you please help me with this problem? Please try to avoid `for`-loop for performance issues.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
In [217]: all_people = np.array([(1, 10), (2, 20), (3, 30), (4, 40), (5, 50)], 
     ...:                       dtype=[('id', int), ('age', float)]) 
     ...:  
     ...: chosen_id = [4, 5, 1]                                                                              
In [218]: all_people                                                                                         
Out[218]: 
array([(1, 10.), (2, 20.), (3, 30.), (4, 40.), (5, 50.)],
      dtype=[('id', '<i8'), ('age', '<f8')])
```

`mask` is a boolean, True/False for the values in `all_people` in order:

```
In [219]: mask = np.isin(all_people['id'], chosen_id)                                                        
In [220]: mask                                                                                               
Out[220]: array([ True, False, False,  True,  True])
In [221]: all_people[mask]                                                                                   
Out[221]: 
array([(1, 10.), (4, 40.), (5, 50.)],
      dtype=[('id', '<i8'), ('age', '<f8')])
```

Since `id` in `all_people` is sorted, we could do the same to `chosen_id`, and get the adding values in the correct order:

```
In [222]: np.argsort(chosen_id)                                                                              
Out[222]: array([2, 0, 1])
In [223]: np.array([1,2,3])[_]                                                                               
Out[223]: array([3, 1, 2])
In [224]: all_people['age'][mask] += _                                                                       
In [225]: all_people                                                                                         
Out[225]: 
array([(1, 13.), (2, 20.), (3, 30.), (4, 41.), (5, 52.)],
      dtype=[('id', '<i8'), ('age', '<f8')])
```

===

Another way to get `Out[222]` that doesn't assume order is

```
In [228]: all_people['id'][mask,None]==np.array(chosen_id)                                                   
Out[228]: 
array([[False, False,  True],
       [ True, False, False],
       [False,  True, False]])
In [229]: np.argmax(_, axis=1)                                                                               
Out[229]: array([2, 0, 1])
```

The equal test on all elements:

```
In [226]: all_people['id'][:,None]==np.array(chosen_id)                                                      
Out[226]: 
array([[False, False,  True],
       [False, False, False],
       [False, False, False],
       [ True, False, False],
       [False,  True, False]])
In [231]: np.any(Out[226], axis=1)                                                                           
Out[231]: array([ True, False, False,  True,  True])  # mask
```

===

We could also get these pieces with `np.where`:

```
In [232]: np.where(Out[226])                                                                                 
Out[232]: (array([0, 3, 4]), array([2, 0, 1]))

In [233]: all_people[Out[232][0]]                # the masked records                                                            
Out[233]: 
array([(1, 13.), (4, 41.), (5, 52.)],
      dtype=[('id', '<i8'), ('age', '<f8')])

In [235]: np.array([1,2,3])[Out[232][1]]         # the sorted addons                                        
Out[235]: array([3, 1, 2])
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use pandas here:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'id':np.arange(1,6),'age':np.arange(1,6)*10})
df.age[df.id==4] += 1
df.age[df.id==5] += 2
df.age[df.id==1] += 3

print(df)
```

The code remains very compact.

```
   id  age
0   1   13
1   2   20
2   3   30
3   4   41
4   5   52
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. But pandas dataframe is not in the scope of my project. I need a solution just using numpy.